# why is the following error coming?failed to load response due to unable to resolve host "api.openai.com":no address associated with hostname

Tags: android, authorization, hostname, openai-api

While creating a Chatgpt app using android, im getting the following lines on the bot side of the chat:
failed to load response due to unable to resolve host "api.openai.com":no address associated with hostname

this is my mainactivity

```
package com.example.chatgptapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
import com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerview;
    TextView welcomeTextView;
    EditText messageEditText;
    ImageButton sendButton;
    List<Message> messageList;
    MessageAdapter messageAdapter;


    public static final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        messageList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        welcomeTextView = findViewById(R.id.welcome_text);
        messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.message_edit_text);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_btn);

        //setup recycler view
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messageList);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(llm);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
            String question = messageEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            addToChat(question,Message.SENT_BY_ME);
            messageEditText.setText("");
            callAPI(question);
            welcomeTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        });

    }

    void addToChat(String message, String sentBy) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                messageList.add(new Message(message, sentBy));
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount());
            }
        });

    }
    void addResponse(String response){
        messageList.remove(messageList.size()-1);
        addToChat(response,Message.SENT_BY_BOT);
    }

    void callAPI(String question){
        //okhttp
        messageList.add(new Message("Typing... ",Message.SENT_BY_BOT));
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonBody.put("model","text-davinci-003");
            jsonBody.put("prompt",question);
            jsonBody.put("max_tokens","4000");
            jsonBody.put("temperature",0);
        }catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON,jsonBody.toString());
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions")
                .header("Authorization","Bearer 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")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new com.squareup.okhttp.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                addResponse("Failed to load response due to " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        String responseBody = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("choices");
                        String result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("text");
                        addResponse(result.trim());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    addResponse("Failed to load response due to " + response.message());
                }
            }
        });





    }


}
```

and this is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_layout"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/welcome_text"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Welcome to ChatGPT\nAsk Something"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="28dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:hint="@string/write_here"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_btn"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_btn"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24" />



    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

its some error with the url, header, post and build, im not able to understand what, can someone help me?

Comment: Your phone is unable to resolve that domain name.

Comment: what can I do for this?

Comment: Perhaps the service is not available where you are. Are you able to reach that server in a Web browser?

Comment: yes i can reach that server